# Загрузка dll в программу

Tags: c#, dll

Я пользуюсь System.Data.SQLite dll.

Такой вопрос: как мне сделать, чтобы, в зависимости от разрядности, подключалась нужная dll, ибо их две версии (для 86 и для 64)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если интересует подключение различных сборок в процессе выполнения программы, то для этих настроек можно использовать [конфигурационный файл приложения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1xtk877y%28v=VS.110%29.aspx). В частности элемент [assemblyIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0yt6ck0%28v=VS.110%29.aspx).

В Вашем случае такая конфигурация будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.98.0" href="bin\x86\System.Data.SQLite.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.98.0" href="bin\x64\System.Data.SQLite.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Вам нужно только правильно указать версию Вашей библиотеки, ее публичный ключ и пути к файлам.

Comment: Спасибо большое, но можно поточнее? просто с такой темой в первый раз сталкиваюсь, я создал конфигурацию...вставил ваш код и указал свои данные. удалил ссылку на длл, но программа теперь не компилируется ибо у меня же указано using System.Data.SQLite; а ссылки нету

Comment: @Corle удалять ссылку на сборку не нужно. Просто указав такую конфигурацию в своем проекте вы объясните по какому пути нужно загружать эту сборку. А путь этот будет меняется в зависимости от разрядность системы. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx тут можно почитать как происходит поиск сборок во время выполнения.